# Invoking a static class property indicates that the object reference is not set to an instance of the object

Tags: c#, wpf

I wrote a static class, as shown below:

```
namespace BkhText
```

{
static class Data
{
//自定义事件委托

```
    //发送信息
    public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(string e);
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChangedHandler;

    //定义数据类型
    private static string data1;

    public static string MyProperty_data1
    {
        get
        {
            return data1;
        }
        set
        {
            data1 = value;
            propertyChangedHandler(data1);
        }
    }

}
```

}

When I assign a value to it somewhere else, it will prompt

```
        private void Button01_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {  
        Data.MyProperty_data1 = "test";
    }
```

the object reference is not set to an instance of the object.I hope you could help me. And Thanks

Comment: `propertyChangedHandler` is `null` because nothing has subscribed to it.

Comment: See the `Events (C#)` section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/3181933).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm new hand, could you help me modify it？ Thanks a lot.

Comment: `propertyChangedHandler?.Invoke(data1);` should do it.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) for information on what `?.` does.

Comment: Be aware that in order to make a static property change event work with WPF data binding, it must adhere to a naming convention. It must either be named `StaticPropertyChanged` or `MyProperty_data1Changed`. In the former case, you must not pass a string as argument, but a PropertyChangedEventArgs with the correct property name. See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/getting-started/whats-new?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-to-static-properties